# How to show $f:\mathbb{Z}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{+}, f(n) = n!$ is one-to-one?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I've given this a good effort but I'm pretty stuck.

> How to show $f:\mathbb{Z}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{+},$  $$f(n) = n!$$ is one-to-one?

I'm quite sure the function is one-to-one as $0$ is not an element of the domain, so $f(0)=f(1)$ is not a concern.
However doing something like setting $f(m)=f(v)$ where $m,v$ are arbitrary elements of the domain doesn't really work, since $n!$ doesn't have an inverse.

I was able to get something working algebraically by also doing $f(m+1)=f(v+1)$, but I'm quite sure it is circular to do something like that.

Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: If $m \leq n$ then $m!=n!$ implies $1=n!/m!=n(n-1)\cdots(m+1)$, can you use this perhaps?

Comment: I did the things indicated in my original post, and also tried some things with inequalities, showing that for n>=1, (n+1)! > n! so each unique n must be bigger (and thus different) from the last but I couldn't quite get it to work right. Am I on track with that at least?

Comment: You can also use the fact that $f$ is strictly increasing thus injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose without loss of generality that there exist integers $m, n$, such that $m > n > 1$ and $m! = n!$. This implies: $$1 \times 2 \times 3 \times \cdots \times n \times (n+1) \times \cdots \times m = 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times \cdots \times n   $$

which in turn implies $$1 < n \times (n+1) \times \cdots \times m = 1$$

a clear contradiction. Hence for all $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $m \neq n$, we have $m! \neq n!$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very clear.